# SpriteKit PhysicsBody non-rectangular collision

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, swift2

```
    pipeUp.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: pipeUp.size)
```

in this coding I used the `rectangleOfSize` for collision physics body, but if I want to use by pixel just the shape of the image, what I should use instead of `rectangleOfSize`?

Comment: Do note,  that didBeginContact will fire multiple times due to their being multiple contact points,  you will have to handle this in code

Answer (score 1):

You should make a `CGPath` that is the shape of your object, and use `SKPhysicsBody`'s `init(polygonFromPath path: CGPath)` as [described here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithPolygonFromPath:)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a physics body based on the texture:

```
pipeUp.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture:pipeUp.texture)
```

It will create an alpha mask texture for you, so any pixel that has an alpha 0, will not be included in the physics body.

Edit:

@classenApps made me realize I made an extension to do this, so I will add it for the answer to be correct.

```
extension SKPhysicsBody
{
    convenience init(texture: SKTexture)
    self.init(texture:texture,size:texture.size())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use KnightOfDragon's method with the addition of the `size`: parameter like this:

```
pipeUp.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: pipeUp.texture, size: pipeUp.size)
```

I believe there is/used to be a memory leak using the `CGPath`.

Comment: actually, your way is the way to do it,  based on AppleDocs,  I have an extension that does it without the size

Answer (score 0):

If you need to explicitly tell the texture what alphaThreshold to use, another solution can be:

```
/**
     Creates a body from the alpha values in the supplied texture.
     @param texture the texture to be interpreted
     @param alphaThreshold the alpha value above which a pixel is interpreted as opaque
     @param size of the generated physics body
     */
    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    public /*not inherited*/ init(texture: SKTexture, alphaThreshold: Float, size: CGSize)
```

So the code will be:

```
pipeUp.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: pipeUp.texture, alphaThreshold: 0.3, size: pipeUp.size)
```