# Cannot convert value of type 'Bird', Type 'to expected argument type 'SKTexture'

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

```
self.name = "Bird"

self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: Bird, size: self.size)
```

I am having trouble with Physicsbody, I try to use bird shape for the collision instead of circleRadius. How can I fix the problem?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38436882/spritekit-physicsbody-non-rectangular-collision

Comment: what method is this called in?  do we have a texture,  if so, instead of Bird, you would use self.texture

Answer (score 1):

If you want to subclass `SKSpriteNode` to define your own sprite and you want to use the texture for physics collision detection then here's the code

```
class BirdSprite: SKSpriteNode {

    init() {
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "birdImage")
        super.init(texture: texture, color: .clearColor(), size: texture.size())
        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: texture, size: texture.size())
        name = "Bird"
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```